# UITabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage in iOS 4

Tags: uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

i want know how i can use an image to the selected item in a UITabBar, in ios5 i'll do in this way:

```
[[myTabBar tabBar] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBar_Activated.png"]];
```

but in iOS 4 that line give me an error, how i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this..
This will show the image when you select the tab...

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selection-tab.png"]];
```

And this will set the image for tab bar...

```
UITabBarItem *tab1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Me" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-me.png"] tag:1];
//Set this tabitem in current view's tabBar.
[self setTabBarItem:tab1];
```